# Vaadin Excel Uploader issue

Tags: java, excel, spring-boot, vaadin

I am developing a web application using Spring Boot and Vaadin Framework which suppose to have a feature of processing Microsoft Excel documents, storing data from spreadsheets in custom Java objects, and finally persisting them to database. I am using [the Excel Uploader](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/excel-uploader/8.1.0) add-on from Vaadin's directory which handles this kind of stuff.

As it is shown in [the official examples](https://github.com/basakpie/vaadin-exceluploader-addon/blob/master/README.adoc) to this add-on, it perfectly works for populating Vaadin Grid component with data from a spreadsheet and reads it properly with no issues. However, I have problems when I try to store this data in a custom object and call any method of this data type, due to the ClassCastException. This exception is thrown because the program tries to cast objects of the same data types. The thing is that whenever I want to add a SucceededListener using a lambda, the data gathered from an excel document is referenced as a collection of the generic Object type, hence it is needed to cast it to a custom object in order to call specific methods. However, when the program runs and I try to upload an excel document via UI this exception is thrown because that collection of generic Objects becomes a collection of custom data types at some moment.

This is the method where the Excel Uploader is configured:

```
public void configureExcelUploader() {
    ExcelUploader<Person> excelUploader = new ExcelUploader<>(Person.class);
    excelUploader.addSuccededListener((event, items)) -> {
        List<Person> persons = (List<Person>) items;
        persons.callCustomMethod();
    });

    Upload uploadButton = new Upload("Upload");
    uploadButton.setReceiver(excelUploader);
    uploadButton.addSucceededListener(excelUploader);
}
```

I probably miss something or simply do not how to do this kind of operation properly. Is there anyone who knows a proper way of storing results in a custom object in this particular case?

Comment: What type is `items`?

Comment: @ImpulseTheFox within the lambda it is List<Object>. But once I run the program it becomes List<Person> at some point.

Comment: Please show the full error message, including stack trace

Comment: Please also include your `Person` class. Do you use annotations to map columns?

Comment: @AndréSchild unfortunately, I don't have access to the source code at the moment, but briefly, it was like "Upload failed. ClassCastException: package.Person cannot be cast to package.Person".

Comment: @SteffenHarbich consider that it is a simple pojo class with first name and last name fields which are annotated with "ExcelColumn".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by removing DevTools from maven dependencies and everything worked perfectly.